Split a group of images vertically with output in different directories
I have a directory with 170 png photos on a Linux Mint machine, which I want to split in half. I came up with a solution, but it didn't work properly, because it overloaded the cache. The command I had written and has worked for 1 image was:
convert -crop 50%x100% ../image_location.png image_location_cropped.png

I tried to write a loop, but I wasn't successful. Something like this:
for i in Testovnica_chemia-???.png
do
    convert -crop 50%x100% ../Testovnica_chemia-???.png Testovnica_chemia-???_upravene.png
done

Error message looked like this:
convert-im6.q16: cache resources exhausted `../Testovnica_chemia-056.png' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/4083.

How should I modify it?

How did you write the loop? In what way wasn't it successful?

Does the command you've shown us do what you want for the one photo, image_location.png?

What do you mean, "it overloaded cache"? What cache? What error message? What result?

Show your minimal code that is failing and show the exact text of error messages. If other evidence is used to show that you have a problem, please try to use text, not images, as readers may want to use their browser search to find specific text OR to copy/paste your error message for research and testing. Use the {} tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to achieve correct code/data/output/errMsg formatting.

When you say convert -crop 50%x100% ../Testovnica_chemia-???.png Testovnica_chemia-???_upravene.png, you are trying to process all the files at once (the fact that you do it inside a loop doesn’t help).  You need to use "$i" in your loop to handle a single file.

There are more problems in the loop. The part for i in Testovnica_chemia-???.png will expand to matching files in the current directory, but convert -crop 50%x100% ../Testovnica_chemia-???.png Testovnica_chemia-???_upravene.png will access file names of this pattern in the parent directory and differently named files in the current directory. Please [edit] your question and show an example of the involved directory names and 2 or 3 input and corresponding output files. (It will be easier to run the loop from the directory with the input files.)

It looks like you created the loop but didn't use the loop variable
for src in ../Testovnica_chemia-???.png
do
    num="${src##*-}"
    num="${num%.png}"
    dst="Testovnica_chemia-${num}_upravene.png"
    echo "Processing $num" >&2
    echo convert -crop 50%x100% "$src" "$dst"
done

Replace echo convert with just convert when you are confident the loop will do what you want

There is a fundamental misunderstanding of looping. Let's go through your code:
for i in Testovnica_chemia-???.png
do

Your loop will run with i being every instance of Testovnica_chemia-???.png, so Testovnica_chemia-001.png, Testovnica_chemia-002.png, etc.
    convert -crop 50%x100% ../Testovnica_chemia-???.png Testovnica_chemia-???_upravene.png

Instead of using the file that i points to, you're now using every instance of Testovnica_chemia-???.png as argument. So every time you go through the loop, you're executing
 convert -crop 50%x100% Testovnica_chemia-001.png Testovnica_chemia-002.png Testovnica_chemia-003.png ....

The Testovnica_chemia-???_upravene.png probably won't match anything, so, if convert would not crash, you'd end up with a filename with question marks in it.
The trick is to use $i in the loop for the filename. @Chris Davies answer does just that.
